# delete keys other than root in heap, a valid practice?

Tags: c, data-structures, heap

I come across various views on whether it is valid for a heap to have an operation that deletes a random key other than the root (max or min), what s the standard implementation of heaps, is it a good practice to implement heap with a delete function for keys other than root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic implementation of a binary heap will only provide the deletion of the root key, but more rich implementations can surely provide the deletion of any other node in the heap. (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Operations) ... "basic" and "internal" operations).

However, unlike the root-delete operation, the deletion of another (randomly chosen) key needs the information as to *which* key to delete. And to avoid loss of efficiency, you then need an extra data structure to know *where* in the heap that key is currently stored. It would be a bad idea to scan the complete heap in search for a given key. So you would need an extra data structure that maps each key to an index in the heap array, and this data structure will need to be maintained, which slows down the other operations a bit as well -- though not their time complexity.

Comment: I see, `to which key to delete`, can't we just choose that one to be the last one in the array? Just like deleting the root, we replace the root with the last one and downshift

Comment: If you replace the root, then you are actually deleting the root which is the normal case. The thing is, if you want to delete key 42, you first have to **find** where in the heap that 42 occurs. Once you have located it, it is indeed a similar process (swap with last, and sift up or down). But the process of locating the key 42 is where the issue is. This needs to be an efficient process.

Comment: Well, assuming the basic implementation, that would be O(n) and so for the deletion it would be O(nlogn) which is not Ok, given that deleting root is O(logn)

Comment: That's exactly the point (it is not O(nlogn), but O(n), since O(n) + O(logn) is still O(n)). So you need an extra data structure to map the keys to the indices where these keys are in the heap array, and this information needs to be kept updated. That way you avoid scanning the whole array. Then it is all back to O(logn).

Comment: I see, I think I can do that mapping, I will provide my code for review soon.

Comment: Good to hear. When you decide to post your code for review, make sure to not do that on Stack Overflow but on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Also read their guidelines before posting, so you are sure it fits their rules.

Answer (score 1):

When I read heap like this I think priority queue (see also eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure) which is often a good indication of consensus).

Of course a priority queue can be extended with many functionalities, but the basic ones are insert and delete-max. This can be extended with other features such as the one you mentioned, and many more, but it all depends on what you want it for.

So I would say it is valid to include the function, as long as you satisfy the heap property, but it is also valid to not include is.